# How to install Firefox on a VPS through command line?

Tags: linux, perl, firefox, www-mechanize-firefox

I need to make use of Firefox for web scraping. I am using [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/). So I will need to install Firefox and Mozrepl however I am installing on a vps that does not have a GUI desktop environment and I am running into problems that Firefox requires a GUI/graphics driver.

The perl script will be run with a cronjob.

How can I do this?

Comment: if you've got command-line access, then use your linux distro's CLI packaging system, e.g. `apt-get install firefox`.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation ([WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.51/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox/FAQ.pod)):

> Do I Need An X Session To Run Firefox?
>
> Yes.
>
> If you run a unixish operating system, like OSX or Ubuntu or some
>   other Linux distribution, then Firefox will connect to your X server
>   and display a window there. If you do not want Firefox to actually
>   display on your monitor, many people have had success by running
>   Firefox on another X server separate from the main X server, like
>   Xvfb.
>
> Personally, I would prefer to have a "headless Firefox" that does not
>   need a windowing environment. So far, I am unaware of this actually
>   existing.

So yes, you need to have an X session available.
Enable XForwarding, with ssh, so you can view the remote GUI desktop on your local machine. Then install Firefox via package management, then install MozRepel within Firefox. Once this is done ensure the MozRepel plugin is enabeled. Then use cpan to install the rest:

```
cpan WWW::Mechanize::Firefox
```

Comment: If you just want to fake an X-server without actually seeing the output, then [`Xvfb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) can sometimes be used.

Comment: @amon X is required to calibrade Firefox, install and enable add-ons. Also I've yet to see an working example of WWW::Mechanize::Firefox, e.g. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=962011